# Linking ipython widget dropdown and slider values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I "understand" how to link a text box to a slider (by "understand" I mean how to make it work):

```
from traitlets import link

a = widgets.FloatText(value=4.)
b = widgets.FloatSlider(min=3,max=7,step=0.23,value=4.)
display(a,b)

mylink = link((a, 'value'), (b, 'value'))
```

This results in something like this:

[image: linking widgets]

But is there any way how I can link a dropdown box, whose values would be `list_items = ('case1', 'case2', 'case3')` to the `FloatSlider`, where the corresponding values would be e.g. `(3.4, 5.4, 6.7)` ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can.

### Using `directional_link`

The `link` functionality ties together two traits of the same type. If you need to apply a transformation on one of the traits, you should use `directional_link`:

```
from ipywidgets import Dropdown, FloatSlider
from traitlets import directional_link
from IPython.display import display

a= Dropdown(options=['case1', 'case2', 'case3'])
b= FloatSlider(min=3, max=7, step=0.23, value=4)

def transform(case):
    return {'case1': 3.4, 'case2': 5.4, 'case3': 6.7}[case]

directional_link((a, 'value'), (b, 'value'), transform)

display(a, b)
```

Note that this only goes one way, `a --> b`, so updating the dropdown updates the slider, but not the other way around. If you want the linking to go both ways, you have to use another `directional_link`:

```
directional_link((b, 'value'), (a, 'value'), inverse_transform)
```

### Using `observe`

`observe` is the standard way to listen for a trait change in widgets. This is the way to go if you want to trigger more complicated behavior than just linking two traits.

In your example:

```
def update_slider(change):
    b.value = {'case1': 3.4, 'case2': 5.4, 'case3': 6.7}[a.value]

a.observe(update_slider, names='value')
```

Once again, this goes one way (`a --> b`) only. Observe changes in `b` to make the linking bi-directional